# Numerical Diagonalization of Integral Operator

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, tensors, diagonalization

I'm new to this website and I hope my question isn't too weird. So, I have to diagonalize numerically an *integral* operator. *Integral* means, an operator that takes the input function $f(x)$ and returns the function $ g(x) = \int K(x,y) f(y)$. If I'm not mistaken $K(x,y)$ is called the "kernel" of this operator.

If $x$ is a single real variable, I know how to do this. I consider discrete points along the x-line, and the values taken by $K(x,y)$ on the resulting grid form a matrix! This matrix (call it $M$) can be diagonalized using any math software. Like, by writing eig(M) in MATLAB. But what if $x$ is a vector, which is a set of two or three variables?

How would you proceed in that case? Even if I discretize the variables, $K(x,y)$ doesn't become a matrix but something more weird, a tensor. I can't use MATLAB's eig function on that. Then what can I do? A huge thanks if you can help.

Comment: Diagonalizing an integral operator means finding eigenfunctions. So you should select some basis for the real-valued functions on $R^2$ or whatever domain. If you wanted to imitate your 1D idea you would discretize the domain and take basis elements each equal to 1 at one node and 0 at the rest. Then you choose an order on these to assemble your matrix just as before.

Comment: You are suggesting that I use a basis like, for instance, circular harmonics of the angle times some complete set of polynomials of the radius? But if I've chosen such a set, what do I do then?

Comment: Write your operator in that basis and now you have a standard eigenvalue problem (finite dimensional if the basis was finite dimensional).

Comment: No, the basis would still have two quantum numbers, with infinite values

Comment: In general yes but the same is true in 1D (except with just one "quantum number"). If you want to proceed numerically then you need to restrict attention to some finite dimensional subspace left invariant by K or by some approximation of K. You already did so in the 1D case.

Comment: When you say numbering the points on the grid, you mean that if the grid has size 3, I might label them as 1=(1,1); 2=(1,2); 3=(1,3); 4=(2,1); 5=(2,2); etc., right?

Comment: That is one ordering yes. The point is that you really don't have a tensor, you have a matrix that acts on a "vector" but the vector is naturally indexed by two numbers. You have to force it to be indexed by just one number (a common task in numerics).

Comment: Ok thanks. Only, that becomes a bit complex if the space is $R^4$, say. Then maybe it's better to use other bases?

Comment: It is actually straightforward to define such an ordering in arbitrary dimension. But sure you can use whatever basis you like.

Comment: Do you have a general formula for that? In 2d I know how to do it. I call "ind" the enumeration index you are proposing. For an NxN grid, I obtain the $R^2$ coordinates (i1,i2) from: i1=ceil(ind/N), i2=ind - N*(i1-1).

Comment: ceil is the ceiling function

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/359523/2451

Comment: It's called flattening a multidimensional array. I can't give a formula but I can give a recursion: given a $d$-dimensional array $A$, split it into $n_1$ $d-1$ dimensional arrays $A_i$. Flatten those, and concatenate the results.